# slideshow animation using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code is for slideshow with animation. I want that before every transition i.e. change in image, there is a holds of 1-2 sec  after the animation is over. What should I do?

```
<html>
    <style>
        #slideshow{width:310;height:210;border-style:solid;}
        #imge{
                 position:absolute;left:15;top:15;
                 animation:myfirst 5s;
                 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
                 -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; 
                 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        }
        @keyframes myfirst
        {
            from {width:0;}
            to{width:300;}
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
        {
            from {width:0;}
            to {width:300;}
        }

    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <img id="imge" src="img1.jpg" height="200" width="300"/>
        </div>
        <script>
            var count=1;
            mf();
            function mf(){

                document.getElementById("imge").src="img"+count+".jpg";


                if(count<3)
                   count++;
                else
                    count=1;
                setTimeout("mf()",5000);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're using keyframes already, why not attempt a CSS only slideshow?

Comment: so u want me to use only css and not javascript..

Comment: Just suggesting you could...

Comment: but please tell how to hold the image for 1-2 sec after the animation is over..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var count=0;
mf();
function mf()
{

document.getElementById("imge").src="img"+count+".jpg";

if(count==3)
{
  setTimeout("mf()",8000);
}else{
if(count<3)
count++;
else
count=1;
setTimeout("mf()",5000);

}}
</script>
```

But be better if you done slideshow only on css3 or use overflow css property for create slideshow in js.
[Example css3 slideshow](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/)
This example very help me create in my game map such as in google map. I am very recommended learn this link for understending process of creating animation in web.